# Issue with INTERACT_ACROSS_USERS permission on Android + Fire studio

Tags: android, swift, android-permissions

I'm playing with [Silver](http://elementscompiler.com/elements/silver/) (free Swift implementation) and [Fire](http://elementscompiler.com/elements/fire/) studio on Mac. The basic project from Swift (or C#) template starts and then raises a `java.lang.SecurityException`, output is like:

```
Started
Process started.
Exception on thread 41720e58 () 
Type: java.lang.SecurityException 
Message: Permission Denial: getCurrentUser() from pid=32495, uid=10120 requires android.permission.INTERACT_ACROSS_USERS
```

Of course, there are no `getCurrentUser()` in project, it may be triggered by some internal logic. I run it on device with Android 4.4.

What may cause this issue? There's also a [discussion on forum](http://talk.remobjects.com/t/requirement-for-interact-across-users-in-template-android-application/6175/5) on that.

Comment: Looks like it "requires android.permission.INTERACT_ACROSS_USERS". Also the link you provide someone says: "This looks like a "standard" ignorable error yes. From what I can find on google this was a temporary bug but can be ignored (Fixed in a later Android). Doesn't seem to happen on my own tablet."

Comment: @Thealon The question is why it requires the permission? BTW this is system permission, so users app should never ask for it. And adding permission to manifest file changes nothing. The template application contains just a single "hello world" activity.

Comment: For now they say it's a bug and later on they will know why  this is and what it is. I posted it as a commend and not an answer, just saying.

Comment: @Thealon And yes, I can "ignore" it for a while, but every debug launch requires two extra clicks to continue application execution after the exception, and that is annoying at least :)

Comment: I know that feeling.. haha

Comment: Two extra clicks to accomplish what?   That's not standard Android.  It sounds like either the development machine deployment mechanism is trying to do something it shouldn't, and you are clicking through a dialog there, or else there is some custom exception handler in this environment you are running on top of Android that is putting up a dialog, and the fix needs to be there.

Comment: @ChrisStratton I mean two clicks in IDE debugger. When the exception occurs debugger pauses, but after pressing "Continue" it runs further. Yes, this is weird and occurs not on every device. Unfortunately there's not much info, why is this happening. I hope someone more experienced in Android development may have faced similar edge case and would give a hint :)

Comment: Well, one obvious thing is that you don't normally need to "debug" your app while debugging - ordinarily it is sufficient to merely "run" the debug version and see log messages.  Breakpoint debugging is a luxury, and sometimes one with a lot of overhead expense, so it is not necessarily something to resort to unless you are tackling a problem which is challenging to access by other means.